# for i in range(start,stop,step) Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I want to list a range of numbers and I'm using the "for i in range(start,stop,step)".

```
def range():
    P=36
    for i in range(P+1,0,-1):
        P=P-4
        print(P)
```

I want to list the numbers down to 0 but it goes all the way to -112.

I found that if I do this though:

```
def test():
    P=36
    for i in range(P+1,28, -1):
        P=P-4
        print(P)
```

It would now stop at 0.
Could someone please explain why it does this and doesn't actually STOP at 0? Sorry, I'm new to this and I'm super confused. I would also like the results listed to be able to be referred to afterwards, like stringing the results together to form a line with a polygon but can't simply write

```
list(P)
```

instead of `print(P)`

Comment: Your first example should raise a TypeError because you're overriding `range` with your custom function, so it calls itself recursively and this does not work because of the different parameter number. And in your second example, the indentation is broken.

Answer (score 9):

To create a list from 36 to 0 counting down in steps of 4, you simply use the built-in `range` function directly:

```
l = list(range(36,-1,-4)) 
# result: [36, 32, 28, 24, 20, 16, 12, 8, 4, 0]
```

The stop value is -1 because the loop runs from the start value (inclusive) to the stop value (exclusive). If we used 0 as stop value, the last list item would be 4.

Or if you prefer a for loop, e.g. because you want to print the variable inside it:

```
for P in range(36,-1,-4):
    print(P)
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that using range, creates you a list from 36 to 0 at the beggining and does a for loop 37 times. Your var P has no longer effect on the number of loops if you change it in your loop.

In your first case you'll have `36-37*4 = -112`

In your second case you have your loop executed 9 times thats why you get 0  `36 -9*4 = 0` :)

Try using xrange it should create a value for each loop and i think it will stop at 0.